# view specific queried value of each cell of table using some query in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have one table containing some relation between tables?

- school_id of school_table
- class_id of class_table
- teacher_id of teacher_table
- subject_id of subject_table

Table sample:
[image]

I want to retrieve this whole table with replacing the name of each id from the child tables.
Ex. At time of retrieving the table as table or view i want to see each school name in place of school_id, class name in place of class_id and for other both class and subject with all rows in the table(above shown in image.)

Above shown image is my original table stored in mysql database. and i want this as result:

```
assign_subject_id | Schoolname | teachername | classname | subjectName | session
1                 | UCDC       | rahul       | one       | math        | 2018-19
2                 | UCDC       | gopi        | two       | CS          | 2018-19
```

**school_table:**

```
school_id | schoolname
7         | UCDC
```

and so forth for all table.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are the table & there structures to get data's like `Schoolname | teachername | classname | subjectName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have school_table, teacher_table, class_table, subject_table

each with same pattern as school_table  (school_id | schoolname)

the you need  some join

INNER JOIN if all the relation key must match

```
select a.assign_subject_id, b.schoolname, c.teachername
        , d.classname, e.subjectName, a.session 
from my_table a 
inner join  school_table b on a.school_id = b.school_id
inner join  teacher_table c on a.teacher_id = c.teacher_id
inner join  class_table d on a.class_id = d.class_id
inner join  subject_table e on a.subject_id = e.subject_id
```

LEFT JOIN if the relation key can not  match

```
select a.assign_subject_id, b.schoolname, c.teachername
        , d.classname, e.subjectName, a.session 
from my_table a 
left join  school_table b on a.school_id = b.school_id
left join  teacher_table c on a.teacher_id = c.teacher_id
left join  class_table d on a.class_id = d.class_id
left join  subject_table e on a.subject_id = e.subject_id
```